# Simple Prolog factorial program loading

Tags: prolog, factorial

I am learning Prolog using SWI-Prolog.
Here is my practice code in file `fact.pl`:

```
factorial(N,F) :- N is 0, F is 1;
              N > 0, M is N - 1, factorial(M,G), F is N*G.
```

While I was trying to load this file by using `[fact.pl]`, the interpreter gives me the following error:

```
?- [fact.pl].
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [fact
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: .pl] .
```

I am not sure how this happens, and I am pretty sure what I have done is the standard program loading command.

Anyone has ever seen this please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either `?- [fact].` or `?- ['fact.pl'].` should work

Answer (score 0):

> use  `consult(fact)` or `consult('fact.pl')`

below is another simple program

```
factorial(0,1). 

factorial(N,F) :-  
   N>0, 
   N1 is N-1, 
   factorial(N1,F1), 
   F is N * F1.
```

`the factorial of 0 is 1`

`the factorial of N is F if N>0 and N1 is N-1 and the factorial of N1 is F1 and F is N*F1`

Answer (score -1):

When I compile your program it gave me the following answer.

factorial(5,F).
F = 120 ;
false.

That means your program works correctly.

`factorial(N,F) :- N is 0, F is 1,**!**;N > 0, M is N - 1, factorial(M,G), F is N*G.`

Include the cut operator(!).Then you can avoid the false part in the output.